# Possible to place border on inside of padding using only one div?

Tags: html, css, border

I'm just wondering if anyone knows a way to use only one div to get an inlayed border effect? Or do I have to use two? Here's what I mean:

I'm currently using a div with a border, wrapped inside a div with padding. I have to keep track mentally of which in_wraps go with which out_wraps. I'd like to just have on element on the page that will look like this:

[image: box example]

instead of having to use two divs and match them up. Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
.out_wrap_blk{
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.out_wrap_gry{
    padding: 5px;
    background: #323232;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.in_wrap_grn{
    border: 1px solid #0CFF0E;
    padding: 20px;
}

.in_wrap_blk{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Is it possible to reduce this to just one element or do I have to stick with an outside element wrapped around an inside element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#bor-outline {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  border: 4px solid #292929;
  outline: 4px solid #e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
<div id="bor-outline">
  hello
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that css property even existed!

Answer (score 7):

All you need is the awesomeness of CSS **outline-offset** property:

Here's a **[JSFiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/flamedenise/xjf5s0xL/)**.

**CSS:**

```
div {
    background: #808080;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    outline: 2px solid black;
    outline-offset: -16px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a pseudo-element :

*HTML:*

```
<div id="w"></div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#w{ width:300px;height:300px; background: grey;position:relative; }
#w:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
    top:15px;
    height:266px;
    width:266px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/21sx67a3/1/)

Comment: Thanks, while I tried this solution and it did work, the other answer was a little simpler, thanks though, this is still good to know.